# Twilio/Ruby/Heroku Issue: "ArgumentError: Account SID and auth token are required"

Tags: ruby, heroku, twilio

I've *slightly* refactored [this repo](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/task-router-rails/tree/master), and attempting to deploy to Heroku, but getting this message:

"ArgumentError: Account SID and auth token are required"

I have set those variables as environment variables in Heroku, but doesn't seem to make a difference. Has anyone been down a similar route?

Comment: What did you change in the refactoring? Do you have all the environment variables from the [.env.example](https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/task-router-rails/blob/master/.env.example) set?

Comment: I only made some very slight changes to adapt to my use case - like names of the 'employees', etc. I have populated the live variables in the .env file but I get the same error both locally and on heroku.

Comment: Sorry, that was a bad comment from me! I should have added, have you created a `.env` file and filled that with the credentials? Also, can you include more of the stack trace so I can see where it's happening? Thanks

Comment: Yep, I created the .env file with the credentials, like the example one. Here is what Heroku is saying: https://gist.github.com/shaunhughston/87a6ec08168cd7c237383d4c0bfb92e9

Comment: How did you set the environment variables for Heroku?

Comment: I put them in config variables with TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID & TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN as keys and the variables as the values

Comment: And if you run `heroku config` do you see those variables?

Comment: Yep it returns the variables

Comment: Shauns-MacBook-Pro:task-router-rails-master shaunhughston$ heroku config -a tvi
=== tvi Config Vars
TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID: AC7defe1XXXXXXXXXXX
TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN:  fbbb04bXXXXXXXXX

Comment: I just added the Xs for this message, but it is showing the full variables

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas! The vars should be taken straight from the env and used in the app at the point that it throws. Can you try logging the `ENV` in that file before it raises and see what is there?

Comment: Will try that. Thanks :-)

Comment: Couldn't solve it, I burnt it to the ground and started from scratch. All good now :-)

Comment: Well that is totally weird! Glad it's working now for you!